# How to tag questions for Ubuntu Userspace in Windows?

Tags: discussion

There can be various questions related to Bash Shell on Windows 10. For example bash, command-line, installation of a package etc. We can barely categorize many of them into our existing tags.

I came across this question [Where is the Ubuntu file system root directory in Windows NT subsystem and vice versa?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/759880/where-is-the-ubuntu-file-system-root-directory-in-windows-10-subsystem) It is a typical example of [windows-bash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/windows-bash) question.

Do we need separate tag(s) for Ubuntu Userspace in Windows questions for better readability?

We can create **either** one [ubuntu-on-windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) and put it along with existing tag(s) in the questions where it is applicable **or** several tags for questions about Ubuntu Userspace in Windows.

Comment: Microsoft calls it "bash on ubuntu on windows". I think `ubuntu-on-windows` is more appropriate than `windows-bash`. That said, I do feel that such questions should be directed to MS community.

Comment: I would flag it [off topic](http://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do) and not bother with the tag.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[ubuntu-on-windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ubuntu-on-windows) seems the most appropriate.

Comment: And it's done. Let us not speak of this ever again.