# Should questions like this be migrated to Super User?

Tags: discussion

I answered [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875437/ubuntu-updated-while-in-windows-10) today. The OP's [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875437/ubuntu-updated-while-in-windows-10#comment1360070_875442) indicated that the problem was actually a Windows issue to do with Ubuntu Userspace for Developers under Windows 10. Should the Q & A be migrated to SuperUser, Closed as off-topic, or left as is?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

WSL {Windows Subsystem For Linux} [is supported on Ask Ubuntu](http://meta.askubuntu.com/a/15230/208574), and therefore the question is on-topic.

While we're not obligated to support the install of Windows, we sort of do have a responsibility to support the simulated version of Ubuntu, as well as the LXSS framework (sort of like Wine), similar to how we supported an Ubuntu install in addition to the Wubi installer at one point in time.

In particular, this question isn't talking about Windows itself doing any updating. [WSL has been known to run `sudo apt update` by itself whenever it feels like it](https://github.com/Microsoft/BashOnWindows/issues/841), which seems to be what the OP was talking about. If a Windows update called it, it was still a [LXSS](https://github.com/ionescu007/lxss) action, and therefore is supported here.

Comment: Well since the question I linked was about a Windows update, I'm not sure what you mean. Perhaps I'm not understanding the use of the word container in this context and how that relates to an update to Ubuntu Userspace on Windows 10. Pardon my confusion. Can you clarify? I think your saying on topic here in this case. Is that correct? Thanks. ;-)

Comment: @ElderGeek Edited for clarity.

Comment: +1 (not looking forward to having to deal with windows auto updates though, or stuff written under the windows environment...) , (irrelevant) but please keep reminding me I need to find a less generic profile pic (Ill draw one :)

Comment: @Wilf Oh, sorry. I generalized my icon for reasons. I'll change back *eventually*.

Comment: -1. Your post misses Elder Geek's question entirely. WSL is on topic, but OP asks about something that windows does, not something about Ubuntu. Basically, I see the question as this: "Hey, I'm dual booting with Ubuntu, but my Windows has an issue" .

Comment: @Serg OP's question is "What is this Ubuntu screen running inside Windows?" This question is about WSL (even though OP doesn't realize it).