# Where is the border between Ubuntu and Windows while the questions are WSL related?

Tags: discussion, windows

Recently I've provided answers on few questions related to WSL, but, IMO, they are more Windows related rather than Ubuntu. For example:

- [How can I 'open in terminal' when using Ubuntu subsystem on Windows 10?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1167821/566421)
- [Ubuntu 18.04 on WSL cron daemon not running after reboot](https://askubuntu.com/q/1165969/566421)

So, whether such questions should be answered? What criteria we could keep in mind to decide which of such questions are off-topic or not?

Comment: A similar discussion on meta posted recently: [Where is the line of topicality where WSL is involved?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/18772/where-is-the-line-of-topicality-where-wsl-is-involved)

Comment: This is not a product I personally know anything about but from looking at the opinions of others and the history of what is supported here, it would seem to me that any questions that are about using WSL or running something on it, like the ones you link, would be on topic. We wholeheartedly support official canonical/ubuntu products and that is that WSL is. So I guess you can feel free to answer them.