# How can I interact with someone who has commented on my post without adding another comment? What are some ways that I can improve my question?

Tags: discussion

I have a question about my Ask Ubuntu post: [In Windows Terminal running Ubuntu, how can I make the default directory be ~ (/home/jake) instead of / (root)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1177723/in-windows-terminal-running-ubuntu-how-can-i-make-the-default-directory-be)

Someone commented on my question and told me to edit my post without adding a comment reply. The instructions that I received from them did not work and did not augment my situation. I followed the link in their comment but the powershell commands on that site weren't working either.

It has only been a day, but there hasn't been any other activity on my question. If I'm patient will an answer likely come, or does my question look dead? What can I do to increase the chances of receiving an answer?

Note that I'm fairly new to Linux and I am brand new to StackExchange. I want to learn how to use this platform effectively and efficiently!

Answer (score 14):

Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!!!

I have been on the site since 1.5 years which is very less than some big veterans. As a new user, it happens that one don't know how the site actually works. We all make mistakes, but it's the duty of *oldies* to guide new users. As this point of time, I can't see that comment which asked you to edit your post to add details without adding a comment reply.

Actually, this site isn't a forum and doesn't work in a threaded form. All the details that are related to the question are expected to be in the post only. But new users generally post them as a comment. In comments, the formatting is *horrible* and difficult to interpret the line breaks. So, that comment might have asked you to add the details to the question itself using "edit" button. However, you can always ping the users (who commented earlier/who edited the post) in the comment section and let them know that you have added what they asked.

I see that your question is about Ubuntu on Windows 10. Since this is a Ubuntu community, there are very less number of people here who actually use WSL in their daily life due to its limitations. Therefore, less people are aware of the issues/problems in that. [Also, some might consider the issue as a Windows problem (which is off-topic here).](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/15229/do-we-consider-ubuntu-on-windows-10-the-same-as-an-official-ubuntu-flavour-do)

No question on Stack Exchange network is dead. It is always open (if not closed/deleted/locked) to receive answers. Being patient and providing all the information about the issue is all you can do. Formatting also matter a lot. Although, visualizing thing is good but try to post text wherever possible. In your question you provided the image of the configuration. However, in my opinion text would have been better. It allows the other users to search your question efficiently, load the Q&A on text only browser/slow network connection, copy and trying to reproduce the issue. And remember to follow your own post, post updates like what have you found, if you found solution on your own, please post it as an answer.

Help center is your friend. Have a look at it thoroughly to get an idea what to post and how to post.

> I'm fairly new to Linux and I am brand new to StackExchange. I want to learn how to use this platform effectively and efficiently!

For this I can only suggest: participate and engage more. See what people are posting, how they are getting their questions solved, reading some of the brilliant answers. In short, learning shouldn't stop :)